# How can I remove previous 2 fragments from viewpager adapter once I swipe to open 3rd fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have three fragments in view pager adapter. I can swipe left to right or right to left and get those fragments displayed. But, I want to prevent user from swiping back once he gets to the third fragment. Like, he should not be able to view previous two fragments once he opens the third fragment

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

    super(fm);
    mFragmentManager = fm;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        switch (i)
        {
            case 0 :
                return new FragmentOne();

            case 1 :
                return new FragmentTwo();

            case 2 :
                return new FragmentThree();

            default :
                break;
        }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View v = views.get (position);
    container.addView (v);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView(views.get(0));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able. Checkout android developers docs.
[FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#destroyItem(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int,%20java.lang.Object))

> public void destroyItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
>
> Remove a page for the given position. The adapter is responsible for removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure this is done by the time it returns from finishUpdate(ViewGroup).

Comment: so, in this case, if I use destrouItem, I can only pass single position! How can I pass 2 fragments? Like, once I load 3rd fragment, I should not be able to go back to fragment 2 and fragment 1